# expo failed to complete tunnel connection

Tags: react-native, expo

It was working fine yesterday but when I open my project in this morning, it showed me "Failed to complete tunnel connection". The project was created using expo and it is a fresh project (I haven't code anything at all). I have tried restarting and reopening the project several times but no luck. I'm using Manjaro Linux
[image: error message on my android emulator]

Comment: Do you use the expo cli or the gui?

Comment: i use expo xde gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Try to change from localhost and to tunnel or lan and the back to localhost, i have had this problem multipule times in the past and this was the solu
tion.